# Estimating one logit vs. two logits using 2 dependent variables (i.e. restricting the two logits to have the same coefficients

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, logit

I have a data set where a person has no disability, a mild disability, or a severe disability.  I want to determine of the model for mild and severe disabilities are the same.

I estimated three logits using the same set of independent variables (X's)

In the first model the dependent variable Y1 = 1 if they have any disability (mild or severe) and 0 otherwise

Then I estimated two other models.  The first has the dependent variable Y2=1 if they have a mild disability or 0 otherwise.  And then I estimated a logit with Y3=1 if they have a severe disability and 0 otherwise.  (In other words Y1=Y2+Y3)

How do I use the the results to test if anything is gained by estimating the two models separately, or if it is better to estimate the first model, thus restricting the coefficients on for models 1 and 2 to be the same

Answer (score 4):

You should use a [multinomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logit) or [ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) logit model. These are generalizations of the binomial logit model.

The multionomial logit model is a generalization to outcome variables with an arbitrary number of levels.

The ordered logit model is also a generalization to outcome variables with an arbitrary number of levels. The difference is that here the levels have to follow an "order".

I would estimate a model (multinomial or ordered) with "no disability" as the baseline outcome. Then I would test if the coefficients for the "mild disability" and "the severe disability" outcomes are equal.

As there seems to be an ordering (no - mild - severe) in your dependent variable, the ordered model looks like the better choice. It's upon you to decide. You could also have a look at the domain specific literature for this.

The odds are very high that multinomial and ordered logit models are implemented in your favourite statistical software package, respectively in the software package you use.

Comment: That's a good thought, but it throws away the information coming from the ordering of disability levels.  Is there a reason you are not suggesting, say, an [ordered logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) model?

Comment: Right. I should have mentioned it ... I will amend my answer.

Comment: The only reason you don't see more votes after the edit is that I had already upvoted your answer :-).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I estimated the multinomial and the ordered logit.  Turns out the determinants of mild and severe disabilities are different -- and the multinomial works better  (in fact several of the coefficients change sign) -- but that is actually in line with what we hypothesized based on the causes of various disabilities in this country.  Thanks.